# Forcing post with checkbox array input / workaround

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

Sorry for the bad title.. I am trying to figure out a workaround to this fairly simple problem I am having.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="test[description][]" / >
<input type="checkbox" name="test[confirm][]" value="1" / >
```

The html can be cloned by jquery..the problem I am having is that the checkbox wont post unless it's checked (this is what it's supposed to do I know). This messes up my PHP to check the checkbox index to see if it's checked.. if you clone this 3 times then leave the middle checkbox unchecked..but check the first and last.. the last checkbox gets index of 2 when it want it to be 3.

any suggestions are appreciated thank you.

Comment: That's how checkboxes are supposed to behave. Unchecked checkboxes are NOT submitted, and by their absence from the POSt data, you know they weren't checked. If you need to detect this, then enforce keys on each checkbox. `test[confirm][0]`, `test[confirm][1]`, etc...

Comment: You can inject the values in hidden fields prior to form post and then ensure that the data is posted with the appropriate indices.

Comment: Thank you.. I was attempting to do something like you suggested @MarcB but ran into issues with it incrementing properly in my javascript. This would work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you're trying to do it. There's no way to differentiate which checkboxes were checked as written. You can either:

1) Encode the position in the element name.

2) Create hidden fields, which will be sent, to record the checked/unchecked value. Initialize with something like:

```
<input id="hidden-1" type="hidden" name="test[description][]" value="0" />
<input id="check-1" type="checkbox" />
<script>
   $('#check-1').click(function() {
      var $hidden = $('#hidden-1');
      $hidden.val(hidden.val() == 0 ? 1 : 0);
   }
</script>
```

If the number is dynamic, you could encapsulate all that to generate the bindings dynamically as well.